# How to specify a password for Redis and his sentinels?

Tags: redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

We going to use ServiceStack.RedisClient, but I was not able figure out how to define a password for sentinels and masters.

I've tried pwd@ipv4:port but no result.

Our code is:

```
        var sentinelHosts = new[] { "node1:26379", "node2:26379", "node3:26379" };
        var sentinel = new RedisSentinel(sentinelHosts, "mymaster");


        var manager = sentinel.Start();            


        while (true)
        {
            using (var client = manager.GetClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(client.IncrementValue("MyTestKey"));
                }
                catch (RedisException ex)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine($"Error {ex.Message}");
                }                    
            }

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify to use passwords for connecting to masters / slaves with an [Custom Redis Connection String](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#custom-redis-connection-string), e.g:

```
sentinel.HostFilter = host => "pwd@{0}".Fmt(host);
```